# Expected to return a value in arrow function. (xo code style)

Tags: javascript, eslint

My CLI Node.js project is using the [XO Code Style](https://github.com/sindresorhus/xo) and i've got a problem with 1 error. Here is the output when i run "xo" command:

```
×  31:15  Expected to return a value in arrow function.
```

Here is the code :

```
to.map(item => {
        if (currencies[item]) {
            loading.succeed(`${chalk.green(money.convert(amount, {from, to: item}).toFixed(2))} ${`(${item})`} ${currencies[item]}`);
        } else {
            loading.warn(`${chalk.yellow(` The ${item} currency not found `)}`);
        }
    });
```

If you want, you can also view the full file [HERE](https://github.com/xxczaki/cash-cli/blob/master/bin/cash.js).

I was searching for a eslint rule, but i couldn't find one :( What should i do to ignore/fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XO Code Style is pointing out that your `map` callback never returns a value, but `map` expects the callback to do so.

> What should i do to ignore/fix this error?

Use the right tool for the job. If you're not *mapping* the entries into a new array, don't use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map); use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (or [any of the many other ways to loop through an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)). The purpose of `map` is to create a new array with entries that are a transformation of some kind of the original array's entries.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return a value in the `.map`'s arrow function, which is not intended unless you want an array of `undefined`s.

Use a `for..of` loop instead.